# How to define a highest value with constructor in java?

Tags: java

I want to initialize a new object - Salary with the constructor salary(). However, there's a argument attached to it as 'salary'.

```
class Salary{  

    public Salary(String name, long salary）{    
        this.name = name;    
        setSalary(salary);    
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary){
    this.salary = salary;
    }

    private long salary;
}
```

When a new object salary is created based on this clas, this initial amount of 'salary' (based on constructor) is the highest amount of salary it can ever have. Apparently, I can use other method such as increaseSalary() to increase the salary. Or a method decreaseSalary() in this class to manipulate this value. However, the highest value of 'salary' can never be higher than the value which I passed to it when I create it. How to implement this method?

Comment: You do not want to change the salary once its set by constructor.Am I correct ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You pass in a value for salary, are you asking if it can be defaulted somehow?  Or are you asking if subsequent `Salary` objects should not have a higher salary?

Comment: As per my understanding , what ever the value you will give it will assign .Whats wrong with that.Please let me clear if i am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is answering the question, but I usually set up multiple constructors in cases where I want to default one of the arguments to something (in this case, the highest possible salary). I define the default as a private constant.

```
public class Salary {
    private static final long MAX_SALARY = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private final String name;
    private final long salary;

    /**
      * Create highest possible salary of the given name
      */
    public Salary(String name) {
        this(name, MAX_SALARY);
    }

    /**
      * Create a Salary of the given name and value
      */
    public Salary(String name, long salary) {
        this.name = name; // TODO add null and integrity checks
        this.salary = salary; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? in the constructor:

```
setSalary(Long.MAX_VALUE); // here we ignore the `salary` parameter
```

Or equivalently, in the attribute declaration (but you have to remove the `setSalary()` call from the constructor):

```
private long salary = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Notice that you can change the salary later, any of the above options will leave the default value with the maximum value allowed for a `long`, but you can change it later for a particular instance, simply call `setSalary()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to give your `private long salary;` a default value.

An example could be:

`private long salary = 1_000_000L;`

Note the underscore literals for extra readability of integers/longs.

**However**, by looking more carefully at your code, I do not understand your question fully:

With your current constructor the you are **always** forced to pass on some `salary`, so it can never not be set. And thus there is no need for an initial value.

Comment: But I want to create multiple objects based on this class. That's to say, I cannot initialize all 'salary' with the value 1_000_000L.

Comment: @user2502865 I don't understand the problem you are having, you can create as many instances of `Salary` as you want.

Comment: @user2502865 that's not a problem, you can change the salary later with `setSalary()`. See my answer, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You would store it in a second variable:

```
class Salary{  

    public Salary(String name, long salary）{    
        this.name = name;
        this.maxSalary = salary; // ADD THIS
        setSalary(salary);
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    private long salary;
    private long maxSalary; // ADD THIS
}
```

And then you will be able to change `salary` and `maxSalary` will always be the original amount given to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the initial value in another member (`max` in this case) and compare it at each time `setSalary` is called.

```
class Salary {  

    public Salary(String name, long salary）{    
        this.name = name;    
        this.max = salary;
        setSalary(salary);    
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary){
        if (salary < max) {
            this.salary = salary;
        } else {
            this.salary = max;
        }
    }

    private long salary;
    private final long max;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what the OP has asked, but I have a feeling that it might be what the OP wants, as the other does not make much sense here.

Comment: This is what the OP asked for: `this initial amount of 'salary' is the highest amount of salary it can ever have. How to implement this method?`

Comment: Well, lets see.. We should let the OP decide. :)